# Generated EntityFramework SQL is using varchar instead of nvarchar

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, entity-framework, unicode, collation

I'm having an issue with Entity Framework (6.4.4 - Database First) where the generated SQL is trying to use varchar(max) instead of nvarchar(max)

**Background.**

I have a table in my database which has a varchar(max) column on it. The collation for this table is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.
I have been asked to be able to store non-unicode characters and text in this column (persian, arabic, farsi, etc). So I have run the following SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE LetterTemplates
ALTER COLUMN [Template] NVARCHAR(MAX) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1256_CI_AS NULL
```

The following SQL runs correctly, and stores the characters in the DB properly

```
UPDATE LetterTemplates
  SET [Template] = N'سوالات پیوسته اهل دنیای موجود طراحی اساسا مورد استفاده قرار گیرد.'
  WHERE TemplateID = 2259
```

In my application, I updated my EDMX, removed the entity and re-added it, so the column properties in my entity show as:

```
Fixed Length : false
Max Length : MAX
Unicode : True
Type : String
Name : Template
```

The EntityType in the EDMX XML (storagemodel) is:

```
<Property Name="Template" Type="nvarchar(max)" />
```

The EntityType in the EDMX XML (Conceptual Model is:

```
<Property Name="Template" Type="String" MaxLength="Max" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" />
```

The DbContext is simply

```
 Partial Public Class MyDbContext
     Inherits DbContext
    
     Public Sub New()
         MyBase.New("name=MyDbContext")
     End Sub
    
     Protected Overrides Sub OnModelCreating(modelBuilder As DbModelBuilder)
         Throw New UnintentionalCodeFirstException()
     End Sub
    
     Public Overridable Property LetterTemplates() As DbSet(Of LetterTemplates)
...
...
```

The Generated Class by the edmx is:

```
Partial Public Class LetterTemplates
    Public Property TemplateID As Integer
    Public Property Title As String
    Public Property Description As String
    Public Property Template As String
End Class
```

The line in my code (to save to the db) below:

```
db.Database.Log = Sub(x) Debug.WriteLine(x)
```

shows the generated SQL by entity framework to be:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[LetterTemplates]
SET [Template] = @0
WHERE ([TemplateID] = @1)

-- @0: 'سوالات پیوسته اهل دنیای موجود طراحی اساسا مورد استفاده قرار گیرد.' 
(Type = AnsiString, Size = -1)

-- @1: '2259' (Type = Int32)
```

**HOWEVER:**

SQL Profiler shows the SQL that actually gets run against the db (SQL Server Express 2016)

```
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE [dbo].[LetterTemplates]
SET [Template] = @0
WHERE ([TemplateID] = @1)
',N'@0 varchar(max) ,@1 int',@0='???? ?????? ??? ?????? ?? ????? ????? ??????? ?? ???? ???.',@1=2259
```

if I change `varchar(max)` to `nvarchar(max)` and `@0='?` to `@0=N'ار گیرد` and run that SQL, it runs correctly.

**Question:**

Why is SQL profiler showing that the column is a varchar instead of a nvarchar. have I missed something obvious? i see lots of issues about this the other way round (nvarchar stuffing varchar) but not this way.

**Update:**
Following the comments, the following line seems to be where the problem may be lying.

```
(Type = AnsiString, Size = -1)
```

in the generated SQL, as I am led to believe that AnsiString is used for non-unicode characters. So why is it trying to do this when generating the SQL when the model/entity and Database are all now nvarchar columns?

Comment: You didn't post the entities and DbContext configuration so it's impossible to answer. Latin1 may be specified explicitly in the configuration. Using a Latin1 collation instead of Arabic to store Arabic text is definitely unusual. Why not `Arabic_CI_AS` ? Perhaps this was hard-coded in the configuration too

Comment: It seems you've missed something. `Debug.WriteLine()` should be reporting `Type = String` instead of `Type = AnsiString`. Lurking `[Column]` attributes?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning generated class for the entity/property is simply `Public Property Template As String` - there are no attributes attached to the property.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos no collations are explicitly set in the EDMX. the context is basic. I used CP1256 collation on the column as this codepage has support (and indeed) stores the characters I need.

Comment: `in the EDMX.` which means you use an old EF version as EDMX was abandoned years ago with the introduction of code first. Which version are you using? It's quite possible the weird collation causes it to use `varchar` - what that collation says is `treat this column as ASCII storing CP1256 text`.  Have you tried using `Arabic_CI_AS` instead?

Comment: `as this codepage has support (and indeed) stores the characters I need` - that's not needed and probably *causes* the problem. `nvarchar` is Unicode, it stores *all* characters and doesn't care about codepages. The collation mainly affects sorting. The codepage applies only when converting from/to single-byte text. It's quite possible the weird collation *forced* the use of `varchar`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos fwiw, i removed the 'wierd collation' and let it default back to the table collation SQL_Latin1_CP1_CI_AS, SSMS will store it correctly, entity framework still tries to send it as a varchar. the entity framework version for my project is 6.4.4 and it's using Database First on .net framework 4.7.2